# MySQL migrating Drupal database, Syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql

While migrating our `drupal` site from a hosting company to our main server. I ran into an error creating this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `access` (
`aid` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`mask` varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL default '',
`type` varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL default '',
`status` tinyint( 4 ) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY ( `aid` )
) TYPE = MYISAM ;
```

This returns the following Error:

`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 13`

I exported the database with the following parameters:

```
SQL database
ADD DROP DATABASE
ADD IF NOT EXIST
Add AUTO_INCREMENT value
Enclose table and field names with backquotes
Add CREATE PROCEDURE / FUNCTION
```

And I set the compatibility to MYSQL40.
The version of the old mysql is 5.0.51a the one I wish to Import into is 5.5.16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `TYPE` was deprecated in favor of `ENGINE` in [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html).  It says it is still supported, though I would try to change `TYPE = MYISAM` to `ENGINE = MYISAM` and see if that doesn't help you.